# defining variable with previous variable with fetch

Tags: php

I want to define $querycheckauth in my database with using $querycheckuserid (previous defined) database info, however im getting pdo exception fails and it seems not to work.

```
        $querycheckuserid = $a->con->prepare("select userid from users where auth = ? ");
        $querycheckuserid->execute([$cauth]);
        $querycheckauth = $a->con->prepare("select id from users where userid = ?");
        $useridfetch = $querycheckauth->fetch();
        $querycheckauth->execute([$useridfetch]);
```

I also tried

```
        $querycheckuserid = $a->con->prepare("select userid from users where auth = ? ");
        $querycheckuserid->execute([$cauth]);
        $querycheckauth = $a->con->prepare("select id from users where userid = ?");
        $querycheckauth->execute([$querycheckauth]);
```

however that gives me the following error:

**Uncaught Error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in D:\xampp\htdocs\cinematic\loginwithcinematic.php:42 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\cinematic\loginwithcinematic.php(42): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\cinematic\loginwithcinematic.php on line 42**

Comment: Is it showing an error? If so, which error is it showing?

Comment: The first error just wont echo it when it should and the second is giving the pdo error (just edited the post with the error)

Comment: Why do you have the `execute` with brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it almost right, take a look at following:

```
$querycheckauth = $a->con->prepare("select id from users where userid = ?");
// you need to call execute before fetch
$querycheckauth->execute([123]); // here you have to put the userid in question
// ->fetch() will return array, while you have only single value you can use:
$useridfetch = $querycheckauth->fetchColumn();
```

Now `$useridfetch` contains the `id` you asked for, `echo $useridfetch;`.

The `123` goes instead the `?` like: `select id from users where userid = 123`, you can have variable there but it has to be set to certain value before.

Also you should not try to do `echo $querycheckauth;` that is the source of your error, since value type is PDOStatement which is not convertable to string. You could do `var_dump($querycheckauth);` which wouldn't produce error.